# Link to Source Code from TypeDoc Documentation

Tags: typedoc

I've documented a [function](https://adapter.sasjs.io/classes/sasviyaapiclient.sasviyaapiclient-1.html#getallcontexts) and I can see that the generator has captured the line number:

[image: example of SASjs get Compute Contexts function definition]

Is it possible to configure TypeDoc so that a user can click through to see the actual source code?  The full repository is [here](https://github.com/macropeople/sasjs).

Answer (score 1):

There is a TypeDoc plugin that might address your problem:

https://github.com/gdelmas/typedoc-plugin-sourcefile-url

It doesn't work for my situation because for some reason the URLs to the GitHub source I'm connecting to must contain `blob/master`, which this plugin doesn't add. But I add it here in case it's useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sourcelinktemplate` config to provide source code url using `{path}`, `{gitRevision}` & `{line}` placeholders.

link to documentation: https://typedoc.org/options/input/#sourcelinktemplate

make sure to set disableGit to true.